# Finding the Negative Space in an Image or Cartesian Plane

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, image-processing

> **Please Note** - This is a *Math* question essentially. However, i have also tagged *C#*
>   as this is the language i am working in

## Summary

I'm looking for an algorithm (or name thereof) that can find the *Negative Space* (or space) in an image. The closest i have found [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (which is seemingly close), yet its actually a subset of the actual problem. Namely, to walk through a *Cartesian Plane* traversing every coordinate that isn't filled (or black in my case) to find a mask. Example below

**Example of Dijkstra's Algorithm**

[image]

## The background

I need to tidy up 10's of thousands of images that have artefacts in them. By cleaning up i mean these things specifically :

1. Using *Edge Detection* to find the edges of the objects in the images
2. *Masking* the *Negative Space* so i can covert the image backgrounds to plain white
3. *Cropping* the images to their optimal size.

Currently i'm using *Canny Edge Detection* to find the most important part of the image. I can crop the image fairly well (shown below), and also find all the images that have the problem. However i am having trouble locating the best algorithm (or name thereof) to find the negative space.

---

**Example of the original image**

As you can see the image looks pretty clean, however its not

[image]

---

**Example of the accentuated problem**

The image has lots of artefacts in the background and they need to be removed

[image]

---

**Example of Canny Edge Detection**

This does a wonderful job of cleaning up the image

[image]

---

## The Problem

[Dijkstra's algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) premise is it looks for all the possible paths, its basically a solves the *Travelling Sales* man problem

The problems is; The algorithm actually does much more than i need to do with regards to the weighing and the distance measures , and it stops when it has the shortest path (where i need it to complete the image).

**The pseudo code**

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                 // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10      dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
11      
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Node with the least distance
14                                                      // will be selected first
15          remove u from Q 
16          
17          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
18              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
19              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
20                  dist[v] ← alt 
21                  prev[v] ← u 
22
23      return dist[], prev[]
```

Can anyone suggest an Algorithm or  modify the *Pseudo Code* to *Dijkstra's Algorithms* to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the flood fill algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: @Rotem i could well be!, i never even thought of that

Comment: If so, for any real-world case you would be wise to use a non-recursive implementation, as the risk for stack overflow is quite high.

Comment: @Rotem thanks this is great advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question was simply the **Flood-fill Algorithm**.

However, to solve the entire problem of cleaning subtle artefacts from images, the total solution was as follows.

1. Use Canny Edge Detection with appropriate thresholds to get the outline of objects in the image
2. Use a Gaussian Blur to Blur the Canny results enough so the flood full wont bleed
3. Use a flood fill to create the Mask and apply it back to the original image

Some traps for your for young players.

- PixelFormats, you need to make sure everything is talking the same format
- Not editing the bitmap directly by using scanlines or locked pixels
- paralleling algorithms where possible, in this case the flood fill and Blur where good candiates

## Update

Even a faster method was just to use *Parallel FloodFill* with a *Color Threshold* value

**Color Threshold**

```
public static bool IsSimilarColor(this Color source, Color target, int threshold)
{
   int r = source.R - target.R, g = source.G - target.G, b = source.B - target.B;

   return (r * r + g * g + b * b) <= threshold * threshold;
}
```

**Parallel FloodFill**

```
public static Bitmap ToWhiteCorrection(this Bitmap source, Color sourceColor, Color targetColor, Color maskColor, int threshold, Size tableSize, int cpu = 0)
{
   using (var dbMask = new DirectBitmap(source))
   {
      using (var dbDest = new DirectBitmap(source))
      {
         var options = new ParallelOptions
            {
               MaxDegreeOfParallelism = cpu <= 0 ? Environment.ProcessorCount : cpu
            };

         // Divide the image up
         var rects = dbMask.Bounds.GetSubRects(tableSize);

         Parallel.ForEach(rects, options, rect => ProcessWhiteCorrection(dbMask, dbDest, rect, sourceColor, targetColor, maskColor, threshold));

         return dbDest.CloneBitmap();
      }
   }
}

  private static void ProcessWhiteCorrection(this DirectBitmap dbMask, DirectBitmap dbDest, Rectangle rect, Color sourceColor, Color targetColor, Color maskColor, int threshold)
  {
     var pixels = new Stack<Point>();

     AddStartLocations(dbMask, rect, pixels, sourceColor, threshold);

     while (pixels.Count > 0)
     {
        var point = pixels.Pop();

        if (!rect.Contains(point))
        {
           continue;
        }

        if (!dbMask[point]
              .IsSimilarColor(sourceColor, threshold))
        {
           continue;
        }

        dbMask[point] = maskColor;
        dbDest[point] = targetColor;

        pixels.Push(new Point(point.X - 1, point.Y));
        pixels.Push(new Point(point.X + 1, point.Y));
        pixels.Push(new Point(point.X, point.Y - 1));
        pixels.Push(new Point(point.X, point.Y + 1));
     }
  }
```

**Worker**

```
private static void ProcessWhiteCorrection(this DirectBitmap dbMask, DirectBitmap dbDest, Rectangle rect, Color sourceColor, Color targetColor, Color maskColor, int threshold)
{
   var pixels = new Stack<Point>();

   // this basically looks at a 5 by 5 rectangle in all 4 corners of the current rect
   // and looks to see if we are all the source color
   // basically it just picks good places to start the fill
   AddStartLocations(dbMask, rect, pixels, sourceColor, threshold);

   while (pixels.Count > 0)
   {
      var point = pixels.Pop();

      if (!rect.Contains(point))
      {
         continue;
      }

      if (!dbMask[point].IsSimilarColor(sourceColor, threshold))
      {
         continue;
      }

      dbMask[point] = maskColor;
      dbDest[point] = targetColor;

      pixels.Push(new Point(point.X - 1, point.Y));
      pixels.Push(new Point(point.X + 1, point.Y));
      pixels.Push(new Point(point.X, point.Y - 1));
      pixels.Push(new Point(point.X, point.Y + 1));
   }
}
```

**Direct bitmap**

```
public class DirectBitmap : IDisposable
{
   public DirectBitmap(int width, int height, PixelFormat pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
   {
      Width = width;
      Height = height;
      Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
      Bits = new int[width * height];
      BitsHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Bits, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      Bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, width * 4, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, BitsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());

      using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap))
      {
         g.Clear(Color.White);
      }
   }

   public DirectBitmap(Bitmap source)
   {
      Width = source.Width;
      Height = source.Height;
      Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
      Bits = new int[source.Width * source.Height];
      BitsHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Bits, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      Stride = (int)GetStride(PixelFormat, Width);

      Bitmap = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, Stride, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, BitsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject());

      using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap))
      {
         g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height));
      }
   }
   
   ...
```